# F# function with two generic parameters

Tags: generics, f#

How to define f# function with explicit generic parameters?

I tried this one:

```
let my_function<'a 'b>  (xs: 'a list) (ys: 'b list)  = ....
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a comma inside the angle brackets:

```ml
let my_function<'a, 'b>  (xs: 'a list) (ys: 'b list)  = ....
```

But you don't actually have to *declare* your generic parameters. You can just start using them:

```ml
let my_function (xs: 'a list) (ys: 'b list)  = ....
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this one as well, but compiler reported error and it fooled me into thinking that my generics-list syntax is erroneous whereas the bug cascaded from another place.